# Moving class binds global helper functions to namespace?

Tags: laravel, phpstorm

I have a class like this:

```
namespace App\Bills;

class Addition 
{
   
       public function get() 
       {
            return collect();
       }

}
```

Where `collect` is actually a global helper function. When I rightclick on the classname and click "Move class" and change Namespace to `App\Models\Invoice` this happens:

```
namespace App\Models\Invoice;
use function App\Bills\collect;

class Addition 
{
   
       public function get() 
       {
            return collect();
       }

}
```

Which breaks my code with

```
Error: Call to undefined function App\Bills\collect()
```

because the method collect() is actually a global [Laravel helper](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-collect).

How can I tell PHPSTORM not to escape global functions?

Comment: 1) IDE version exactly? 2) If you `Ctrl+Click` on `collect()` -- where it will take you? 3) Try with all custom (not bundled by default) plugins disabled -- any difference? 4) Try `File | Invalidate Caches`, restart the IDE, let it reindex the project and try again -- any difference? I have been using such refactoring quite a lot in the past (last one was maybe with 2021.1.x version though) and I NEVER had issues with global functions imports like that -- it never touched functions for me (perhaps because of my import settings -- check yours).

Comment: Same. Tried these steps and got `use function collect;` import, as expected.